# mapview casting exception bug?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have added a mapview to my xml layout with a node like so: contained inside a frame

```
<fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="100dip"
          android:layout_height="100dip"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

In my activity i have  referenced it in the onCreate like so:

```
 map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
```

with map defined in globally as MapView map;

```
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.KingNozzle/com.KingNozzle.KNAugmentedRealityActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at com.KingNozzle.KNAugmentedRealityActivity.onCreate(KNAugmentedRealityActivity.java:129)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-02 14:51:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(32368):    ... 11 more
```

my whole layout looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/arFrame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="no signal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <fragment 

          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="100dip"
          android:layout_height="100dip"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment">
          </fragment>

    <com.KingNozzle.Views.KNMultiDirectionalSlidingDrawer
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.KingNozzle"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        my:direction="topToBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        my:handle="@+id/handle"
        my:content="@+id/content">

       <include
           android:id="@id/content"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           layout="@layout/empty_rel" />



        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40px"
            android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
    </com.KingNozzle.Views.KNMultiDirectionalSlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

cant seem to find out why it thinks its a frame view

Comment: did you tried with clean and rebuild?

Comment: i did.. i have not tried getting rid of the gen files and doing a clean..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

Comment: i think you are using MapView ie android google maps V1 which is deprecated, for v2 have a look at this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: im pretty sure i am using v2..  and i actually have it somewhat working now.. all though sometimes when i build the map shows and sometimes it doesn't as if the API key is bad.. but im not changing my keystore or anything..  also when i set zoom to 2 its still way zoomed out

Comment: have you followed all the steps in the above link if yes then post your code and manifest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in you xml change MapFragment to SupportMapFragment

```
<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

In your code

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: What's the supportmapfrag do?

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager does not seem to be a valid call i get an error right in Eclipse asking me to create a method called getSupportFragment  with no import options or to change to getFragmentManager

Comment: you should have google play services installed and also add android-support-v4.jar to external jars

Comment: this is working now.. but i have a different problem.. will post a new question and link it here

Answer (score 4):

It's a `MapFragment`, not a `MapView`. You should look at the documentation of `MapFragment` to do the same thing in `MapFragment`.

So it's possible like this:

```
MapFragment map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
```

Comment: If i reference it as MapFragment in my Activity  MapFragment map = (MapFragment)findviewById(R.id.mapView) I get an error that it can't be casted as a view right in Eclipse  before i even build it.